# Does deriving from a templated base class instantiate the template at the point of the derived class declaration?

Tags: c++

Given the following example code:

```
// Foo.hpp
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
};

extern template class Foo<int>;

class Bar : public Foo<int>
{
};

// Foo.cpp
template class Foo<int>;
```

Will the `Foo<int>` template be instantiated at the point of `Bar`'s declaration? i.e. Does deriving from a templated base class cause an implicit instantiation of the template at that point? My assumption is that yes, it will be implicitly instantiated, but I'm not sure of the relevant section within the standard. If the template is instantiated at that point, then I assume the use of `extern template class Foo<int>;` becomes completely redundant? If this is the case, is there any way to prevent the template from being instantiated every time `Foo.hpp` is included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of an explicit instantation declaration (`extern template`) is to suppress implicit instantiation and force the compiler to generate an external reference instead. However, in the case of a class, an explicit instantiation declaration does *not* suppress implicit instantiation ([temp.explicit]/10). This is because, while it's possible to compile calls to undefined functions (the linker will resolve the call when it sees the definition) there is no similar mechanism for compiling code that instantiates incomplete classes or accesses their members.

In your case, `Foo<int>` will be instantiated when `Bar` is defined, because [temp.inst]/1 says:

> Unless a class template specialization has been explicitly instantiated (17.7.2) or explicitly specialized (17.7.3),
>   the class template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context
>   that requires a completely-defined object type or when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics
>   of the program.

A class type must be complete in order to derive from it, so an implicit instantiation is specified to occur here (and, as previously mentioned, such implicit instantiation is not suppressed by the explicit instantiation declaration).

However, it's not correct to say that the explicit instantiation necessarily has no effect. It *may* suppress the generation of `Foo<int>`'s vtable and/or typeinfo at the time when `Foo<int>` is implicitly instantiated. External references to such entities may be emitted and resolved at link time.

> is there any way to prevent the template from being instantiated every time Foo.hpp is included?

The only way to do that would be to forward-declare `Bar`:

```
class Bar;  // not defined yet
```

However, that would obviously limit what could be done by code that includes the header.

Comment: Thanks, it might also be worth including a reference to [class.derived] `shall denote a ... class type that is not an incompletely defined class` to tie it together ("A class type must be complete in order to derive from it").